# Android fails to detect FTDI chip

Tags: android, usb-device, ftdi

I want to connect FT232R chip to android phone.
I have downloaded FTDI terminal for android from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftdi.j2xx.hyperterm
FTDI program has to startautomaticly when I connect FT232R chip to phone.
Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes android does not detects chip.
sometimes chip is detected only 1 of 10 times.
What could be the reasons? 
[image]

Comment: Schematic of how everything is hooked up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From FT232R datasheet:

```
TEST: Puts the device into IC test mode.
Must be tied to GND for normal operation, otherwise the device will appear to fail.
```

In your schematic the TEST-pin is floating

Comment: I have similar question, can you help? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157781/android-fails-to-detect-ftdi-device